# Updating the date format in a DatePicker when the system date format is changed at runtime

Tags: wpf, datepicker, culture, datetime-format

I am working with a `DatePicker` in a WPF application. I want to change the date format of the `DatePicker` to the system date format.

This is the mail window:

```
<Window x:Class="DateTimeDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="Btn" Width="100" Click="Btn_Click">Click</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The child window is opened using the following code:

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ChiildWindow Cw = new ChiildWindow();
    Cw.ChildDatePicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
    Cw.ShowDialog();
    Cw.Focus();
}
```

This is the child window, which only contains a `DatePicker`:

```
<Window x:Class="DateTimeDemo.ChiildWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ChiildWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <DatePicker x:Name="ChildDatePicker"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

When I open the child window the format is taken from the system culture but if I change the system date format from the control panel after the window opens the format doesn't change.

I have tried the following code in the ChildWindow.xaml.cs file:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```

But when I open the child window the format doesn't change.

Does anyone know what the problem is and how I can solve this issue?

Comment: what exactly your question is? have you solved the issue by assigning the CurrentCulture in code behind?

Comment: No I have Written that The Problem is not yet Solved..I have Tried those things but not yet solved.Can You Please Help me??

Answer (score 1):

According to this answer ( [How to get current regional settings in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542409/how-to-get-current-regional-settings-in-c) ), you can detect culture using this code :

```
private class State
{
    public CultureInfo Result { get; set; }
}

public CultureInfo GetCurrentCulture()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
    var thread = new Thread(s => ((State)s).Result = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
    var state = new State();
    thread.Start(state);
    thread.Join();
    var culture = state.Result;
}
```

Finally, you need to set the CurrentUICulture property to affect UI components :

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = GetCurrentCulture();
```