# Given a dateTime object in C#, show date according to computer locale?

Tags: c#, datetime

Assuming I have a `DateTime` object in C#, and the date is `3rd of january 2011`.

In some locales it would be `03/01/2011` and in some it would be `01/03/2011`

How can I get computer's **regional settings** in order to show the `datetime.toString()` the appropriate value?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542409/how-to-get-current-regional-settings-in-c

Comment: What I intended to say in my answer (deleted after getting -2 in less than 15 sec, really quick people here :)) is that perhaps you should rely on a hardcoded format highlighting clearly what is what. For example: 3-Jan-2011 or Jan-3-2011; and, eventually, include an option for users to change the format. There are many users which are not even aware about the exact regional settings on their computer. Relying blindly on this might drive to unclear situations like 1-3-2011 for a computer with US settings which might be misundertood because the program was created in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

The DateTime.ToString() method, without a parameter, automatically uses the G format parameter which takes culture into account. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.ToString()` without parameters actually uses the **current culture**. So the output of `.ToString()` will be different on multiple machines, depending on their culture.

Comment: thanks. I try to change my reginal settings by going to Region and Language -> Format:.." and change it to something else, but i always get with ToString a dd/mm/yyyy date. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you restarting your program after changing settings? I dunno but reckon the current culture info is likely cached first at process level, and then used to initialize every thread runnable in that process.

Comment: Ok. correct. one last thing, is it possible to make only the years 2digits, as i could do dd/mm/yy, but let the dd/mm to be arranged according to regional settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***String.Format*** with current culture into to do that:

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}", DateTime.Now)
```

Also if you want to change for a different culture you can do the following:

```
String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-IN"), "{0}", DateTime.Now)
```

Output:
7/9/2013 5:04:33 PM
09-07-2013 17:04:34