# How to get date format name in winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, customization

Using windows form application how to get OS region and language date format.

I want string mark in bold in below image.

[image]

Comment: May I know the reason why down vote?

Comment: I haven't dwnted but, may be the reason is your question is broad and there are to many answers possible. for example do you want to get the object of CultureInfo?, want to get date format? as per your question title or you want to get name of regional languages? as per your drawn rectangle. if your actual question is Want to string marked in rectangle then update your question title.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.EnglishName

     or

  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DisplayName


  result of above code is "Thai (Thailand)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Globalization;

CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture; // get the culture of the OS
string cultureName = culture.DisplayName; // get its full name
```

This gives you the culture which was installed with the OS. There seem to be a couple of other static properties of CultureInfo, such as `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`, which may give you what you're looking for.

See the documentation for `CultureInfo`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: In my case above code result in English (United Kingdom) even though my date format is Thai (Thailand).

Comment: Sorry, corrected `CurrentCulture` to `InstalledUICulture`

Comment: In that case result is English (United States). Not Thai (Thailand) Please make sure I have only changed date format not installed culture.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the name of the culture that the thread is using.

```
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

Comment: But I want Date format name not current culture name

Answer (score 0):

This has been already answered: [Previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542409/how-to-get-current-regional-settings-in-c)

Try this,it will solve your problem:

```
class Region
{
    public class Stateinfo
    {
        public CultureInfo Result { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
        var thread = new Thread(
            s => ((Stateinfo)s).Result = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
        var stateinfo= new Stateinfo();
        thread.Start(stateinfo);
        thread.Join();
        var culture = stateinfo.Result;

    }
}
```