# Format DateTime in DataTable column to local settings

Tags: c#, gridview, date-format

We have a gridview in a c# winapp that keeps on showing the dates in the US format, and we would like to use the local PC's date format.  How can we change it:

```
myDataTable.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(DateTime));
myGrid.DataSource = myDataTable;
myGrid.Columns["Time"].DisplayFormat.FormatString = "g";
```

Comment: Where do you get the local PC's culture?

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`? What do you see results right now and which format do you want to see them exactly?

Comment: My local culture is en-ZA, but the app will also run on other countries, so en-GB will also be used.

Comment: It shows the Time column as 3/18/2015 09:10:30, and I would like to see 2015/03/15 09:10:30, but when deployed in GB or US, it should use the local settings as per the PC's settings in control panel.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542409/how-to-get-current-regional-settings-in-c for how to get the Culture settings. Once you have that, converting dates is rather straightforward

Comment: @user1208908 Are you using devexpress?

Comment: Yes, I'm using dev express.

Comment: @guildsbounty the link helps to reset the culture info but for some strange reason I can't seem to set the DisplayFormat.FormatString as the samples are all different than setting a column format.  Will keep on searching through the wide web, but any ideas or samples will be great and appreciated.